# Url rewriting htaccess remove part of url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

First, I know how to rewrite a URL like example.com/test.php?id=1.

What I dont know is how to remove the test.php part of the url so that the new url is called:

example.com/1/

I hope someone know how to do that, and yes, I've read a hundreds of SO items about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by removing if you are about to rewrite old one into new one.
For example you can do it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule tag/s/(.*) test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Welcome on Stack Overflow.

Comment: A brief explanation about apache's rewriteEngine : it does not update the links on your views (You have to do it by yourself), but it translates the already rewrited rules to the native format of your website.